# Opendaylight Data Tree poisoned after leader switch

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-karaf, opendaylight

We are using Nitrogen version (SR1) of ODL. We are trying  2 node cluster and when follower becomes leader (after running the server for 5 - 6 hrs) we observe below exception in karaf.log. When below exception happens we are unable to access MDSAL for any read/write operations.

We call switchAllLocalShardsState API to change follower to be new leader based on "Akka Member Removed" event.

> 1) What does "poisoned" and "No Progress Exception" refer here.
>
> 2) Does "TERM" that we pass as an argument to switchAllLocalShardsState
>   cause    this issue. If yes, please explain the significance of TERM
>   and also    let us know why we are facing this issue only after
>   running the    server for a long time.

```
2018-06-04 11:58:25,452 | ERROR | tAdminThread #20  | 130 - com.fujitsu.fnc.sdn.fw-scheduler-odl - 5.1.0.SNAPSHOT | SchedulerServiceImpl | Get Schedule List Transaction failed : ReadFailedException{message=read execution failed, errorList=[RpcError [message=read execution failed, severity=ERROR, errorType=APPLICATION, tag=operation-failed, applicationTag=null, info=null, cause=ReadFailedException{message=read execution failed, errorList=[RpcError [message=read execution failed, severity=ERROR, errorType=APPLICATION, tag=operation-failed, applicationTag=null, info=null, cause=org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.access.client.NoProgressException: No progress in 31198 seconds]]}]]}
2018-06-04 11:58:25,452 | WARN  | tAdminThread #12  | 261 - com.fujitsu.fnc.sdnfw.security-odl - 5.1.0.SNAPSHOT | IDMLightServer | getContainer: {}
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: ReadFailedException{message=read execution failed, errorList=[RpcError [message=read execution failed, severity=ERROR, errorType=APPLICATION, tag=operation-failed, applicationTag=null, info=null, cause=org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.access.client.NoProgressException: No progress in 31198 seconds]]}
        at org.opendaylight.yangtools.util.concurrent.MappingCheckedFuture.wrapInExecutionException(MappingCheckedFuture.java:65)[583:org.opendaylight.yangtools.util:1.2.1]
        at org.opendaylight.yangtools.util.concurrent.MappingCheckedFuture.get(MappingCheckedFuture.java:78)[583:org.opendaylight.yangtools.util:1.2.1]
        at com.fujitsu.fnc.sdnfw.aaa.idmlight.impl.IDMLightServer.getUsermgmt(IDMLightServer.java:3056)[261:com.fujitsu.fnc.sdnfw.security-odl:5.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at com.fujitsu.fnc.sdnfw.aaa.idmlight.impl.IDMLightServer.init(IDMLightServer.java:1977)[261:com.fujitsu.fnc.sdnfw.security-odl:5.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at com.fujitsu.fnc.sdnfw.aaa.idmlight.impl.IDMLightServer.handleEvent(IDMLightServer.java:3251)[261:com.fujitsu.fnc.sdnfw.security-odl:5.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at Proxyadd8c855_db4c_4e72_b600_2ca57cba8d4d.handleEvent(Unknown Source)[:]
        at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.handler.EventHandlerProxy.sendEvent(EventHandlerProxy.java:415)[393:org.apache.karaf.services.eventadmin:4.0.10]
        at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.HandlerTask.run(HandlerTask.java:90)[393:org.apache.karaf.services.eventadmin:4.0.10]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_66]
        Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Uncaught exception occured during closing transaction
                at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.databroker.AbstractDOMBrokerTransaction.closeSubtransactions(AbstractDOMBrokerTransaction.java:92)[497:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:1.6.1]
                at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.databroker.DOMBrokerReadOnlyTransaction.close(DOMBrokerReadOnlyTransaction.java:50)[497:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:1.6.1]
                at org.opendaylight.controller.md.sal.binding.impl.BindingDOMReadTransactionAdapter.close(BindingDOMReadTransactionAdapter.java:36)[484:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-binding-broker-impl:1.6.1]
                at com.fujitsu.fnc.sdnfw.aaa.idmlight.impl.IDMLightServer.getUsermgmt(IDMLightServer.java:3062)[261:com.fujitsu.fnc.sdnfw.security-odl:5.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
                ... 10 more
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection ConnectedClientConnection{client=ClientIdentifier{frontend=member-1-frontend-datastore-config, generation=1}, cookie=0, poisoned=org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.access.client.NoProgressException: No progress in 31198 seconds, backend=ShardBackendInfo{actor=Actor[akka.tcp://opendaylight-cluster-data@u446.nms.fnc.fujitsu.com:2550/user/shardmanager-config/member-2-shard-default-config#-1532234096], sessionId=0, version=BORON, maxMessages=1000, cookie=0, shard=default, dataTree=absent}} has been poisoned
                at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.access.client.AbstractClientConnection.commonEnqueue(AbstractClientConnection.java:198)[467:org.opendaylight.controller.cds-access-client:1.2.1]
```

Comment: The references to NoProgressException and AbstractClientConnection indicates you've enabled the tell-based protocol of the clustered data store (which is essentially experimental). I'm not too familiar with the tell-based code but I believe NoProgressException means a transaction operation timed out.

Comment: Also what is the "switchAllLocalShardsState" API?

Comment: @TomPantelis : Thanks for your prompt response. switchAllLocalShardsState in the JMX bean function to change shard state for all the shards. We use this JMX Mbean to change state, please let us know if there is alternate approach.

Comment: I forgot about that. I've never used it. There's a better way to implement 2-node primary/secondary by making the secondary non-voting and then promoting the secondary to leader by switching it to voting when the primary fails. This is documented in the online clustering guide in the Geo redundancy section which describes it for 6 nodes but you can use it for 2 nodes - same concept..

Comment: Thanks @TomPantelis, we dont observe this issue after changing protocol to "Ask" in org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.cfg

Comment: @TomPantelis: Could you please explain the difference between "Tell" and "Ask", and which is recommended for ODL. How does "Ask" resolved our issue.

Comment: They're just different implementations of the transaction front-end. tell-based is the new one initially introduced in Nitrogen designed to be more resilient to transient comm failures but is still experimental and there have been fixes since Nitrogen. I'm curious how you even know about it...

Comment: I'll add an answer so you can mark as answered.

Answer (score 3):

The NoProgressException indicates you've enabled the new tell-based that was initially introduced in Nitrogen. It's designed to be more resilient to transient comm failures but is still experimental and there have been fixes since Nitrogen. I would suggest disabling it.

Also, there's a better way to implement 2-node primary/secondary by making the secondary non-voting and then promoting the secondary to leader by switching it to voting when the primary fails. This is documented in the online clustering guide in the Geo redundancy section which describes it for 6 nodes but you can use it for 2 nodes - same concept.